# Passing time from TIBCO to Salesforce Classic

Tags: integration

We have passed a time 17:40:12 from TIBCO to Salesforce Classic, but Salesforce Classic received it as 17:40:12.000 (When checked on Edit Mode) but not 17:40:12 and displays 5:40 PM.

Our locale  English (Australia) - AUD. Our Default Timezone is (GMT+10:00) Australian Eastern Standard Time (Australia/Sydney).

Why does Salesforce change the time format? Any explanation on this?

Note: I have tested this on Salesforce Lightning when typed in 17:40:12 it does accept and display 17:40:12 (HH:MM:SS) format.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is that you're asking here. The only difference between the two times that you posted here is that Salesforce is showing you the milliseconds as well. Is that really an issue? Fields that include time only display hours and minutes in classic (and I haven't looked that closely at LEX), but the data for minutes is still stored correctly if you query the record through, say, the developer console.

Comment: what is the field type for this field in question?

Comment: @Derek F, What we want to accomplish is that: 1. Salesforce to display HH:MM:SS on the case record as the data that was sent from TIBCO HH:MM:SS (ex. 17:40:12 ) 2. Yes, it did receive and stored 17:40:12 however, milliseconds was appended to the time format. We only need SF to receive it as is, as the way we sent it in HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: @cropredy The field type is Time.